# Question about Operator Precedence in C++

Tags: c++

The output is 34 but How this expression evaluated?

Could you please show with parenthesis?

Correct operator precedence is:

> a += ((((((2 * i++) % 5) * 4) + (--j)) - (3 / k)) + 2);

But I think correct should be:

> a += (((((2 * i++) % (5 * 4)) + (--j)) - (3 / k)) + 2);

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 3, i = 12, j = 14, k = 16;
    a += 2 * i++ % 5 * 4 + --j - 3 / k + 2;
    cout << a;
}
```

Comment: You may check [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) if you have any doubts. It describes both precedence and associativity.

Comment: What do you think it should be and how do you come to that conclusion?

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: Usually I'm one of the first downvoters but in this question I don't understand the downvotes. Could someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operators `*`, `/` and `%` have same precedence and are grouped left to right. Therefore it is `((2 * i++) % 5) * 4` and not `(2 * i++) % (5 * 4)`

Comment: in the language of the standard, those operators are **grouped** left to right. “Evaluated” is easily misread here to suggest order of evaluation of their arguments, which is an entirely different matter. +1.

Comment: @PeteBecker Changed it.